# Create multiple plotly express graphs

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash, plotly-express

I am developing a multi-page dash application. I have a `sidebar` containing some options built using `dbc.NavLink` component. One of the option is `bivariate analysis`, this page plots different graphs to perform bivariate analysis. I am using `plotly express` to create different graphs. Also I have theme selector(template can be dark or light) built using `dbc.switch`. I have a dataset having `many columns` and `data size` is also `large`.

I checked that I can not use `make_subplots` to create multiple graphs as `plotly express graphs` do not support this. So currently, To start I have plotted few graphs such `px.bar`, `px.scatter` etc for `few columns` and they are getting displayed.

Before writing more graphs for different columns and combinations, I have few queries for how dash will respond to:

1. On clicking the link(bivariate analysis), I guess it will take considerable time to create and plot all graphs. Does in such cases request will timeout or it will load all graphs?
2. On changing the `template property` of plotly express graphs from `dark` to `light` and vice-versa. Does above same case will happen?

Can someone suggest or share ways or tips to take care while plotting many graphs?